# Could not make dir /$HOME/.ansible/cp: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/$HOME

Tags: python, ansible, supervisord, ansible-runner

I've got a python script that uses the **ansible** package to ping some remote servers. When executed manually (*python devmanager.py*) it works ok, but when the script is managed with **supervisor** it raises the following error:

```
Could not make dir /$HOME/.ansible/cp: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/$HOME
```

The ansible command is quite simple:

```
    runner = ansible.runner.Runner(
            module_name='ping',
            module_args='',
            forks=10,
            inventory=inventory
    )
```

Same user in source and target systems. I've check permissions for the $HOME folder and didn't find anything weird.

Any idea what's is going on? Doesn't it know to translate the $HOME variable?

Comment: Are you using `$HOME` in Python?  It should be `os.environ['HOME']`

Comment: No, that $HOME variable is something ansible uses to create a temporary folder to execute the command. It doesn't belong to my script

Comment: Also see this question, same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31842826/ansible-cannot-make-dir-home-ansible-cp

Answer (score 1):

You may give a try by altering the parameter "remote_tmp" in ansible.cfg.

Default:-`$HOME/.ansible/tmp`

Update:-`/tmp/.ansible/tmp`

On this case who ever the user try to run the playbook will have enough permission to create necessary temporary files in /tmp directory.

Comment: That sounds like a good idea. I tried but it says  __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'remote_tmp'. This is how I tried it:             runner = ansible.runner.Runner(
                    module_name='ping',
                    module_args='',
                    forks=10,
                    remote_tmp='/tmp/.ansible/tmp',
                    inventory=inventory
            ) How should I define it?

Comment: Also tried updating **/etc/ansible/ansible.cfg** but it still uses the default path. I'm using the pyhon api anyway

Comment: Tried all these options to configure cfg, but still gets the default path. ANy idea why? 1st: ANSIBLE_CONFIG (an environment variable), 2nd:
 ansible.cfg (in the current directory), 3rd: 
 .ansible.cfg (in the home directory), 4th: 
* /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg [link](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_configuration.html)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it seems that it doesn't escape the `$HOME` variable and tries to write under `/$HOME`.